# how can improve this query in big mysql database

Tags: mysql, select, explain

my query is simple but 10 seconds long to respond. please check and help me to improve that

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(test.code) AS sumid
FROM
    test
WHERE
    test.state = '03' AND test.type = '0'
        AND test.year = '2020'
        AND test.active IN (1 , 2)
        AND test.status IN (1 , 4)
        AND test.marhale = 0
LIMIT 1
```

explain that show:

```
id  select_type   table  partitions   type      possible_keys                         key                       key_len     ref     rows    filtered          Extra  
1   SIMPLE        test              index_merge type,year,marhale,state,status,active   year,state,marhale,type 2,6,2,1     20354   27.24                Using intersect(year,state,marhale,type); Using where
```

this table is my important table in big database and we have many reports for all of the columns of that this causes us index many of fields.

this show create table of test :

```
CREATE TABLE `tashilat` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `eid` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `hcode` char(15) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `code` char(16) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `listcode` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `year` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1392',
 `ddate` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `type_level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `baseprice` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `prices` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `marhale` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
 `maxmarhale` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `paystatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `marhale_level` smallint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `pdate` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `paymethod` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
 `state` char(2) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `bank` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `branch` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `tdate` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `daccept` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `dcode` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `mtime` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `mshkdate` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ghtime` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `gh` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `submitted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `submittedtype` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `submitteddate` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ztype` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `bdate` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `pcode` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `lastp` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
 `tozihat` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci,
 `ncode` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ndate` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `ccode` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `cdate` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `bcode` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `bdate` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `secindicator` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `hesab` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `stage` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `loantopic` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `baz` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `accept` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `user` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `sdate` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `activetype` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `status_fact` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status_date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `tashilat_idx_bank` (`bank`),
 KEY `tashilat_idx_shobe` (`branch`),
 KEY `submitted` (`submitted`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `listcode` (`listcode`),
 KEY `mshkdate` (`mshkdate`),
 KEY `eid` (`eid`),
 KEY `baseprice` (`baseprice`),
 KEY `code` (`code`),
 KEY `hcode` (`hcode`),
 KEY `marhale_level` (`marhale_level`),
 KEY `type` (`type`),
 KEY `year` (`year`),
 KEY `marhale` (`marhale`),
 KEY `maxmarhale` (`maxmarhale`),
 KEY `state` (`state`),
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `active` (`active`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `sdate` (`sdate`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `ndate` (`ndate`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `cdate` (`cdate`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11293550 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8           COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci
```

my query run in 11 seconds.
with count(*) or with count(test.code) or without limit 1 not diffrence

Comment: perfiomance questionws need more information please see https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions

Comment: Create one composite index instead of separate ones.

Comment: "my query run in 11 seconds. with count(*) or with count(test.code) or without limit 1 not difference" -- The suggestions were more about SQL coding; they rarely impact performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"intersect" tells me that you have a bunch of 1-column indexes, when you should have an 'composite' index with all those columns.  In particular:

```
INDEX(state, type, year, marhale,   -- any order is OK
      status, active)               -- later; in either order
```

That is, *start* with all the columns that are tested with `=`.

Another issue is with `COUNT(test.code)`.  That means "count how many rows have `code IS NOT NULL`".  If you really want "count the number of rows", then say simply `COUNT(*)`.

If you want to test NULLness, then tack `code` onto the *end* of my recommended index.  That way, it will be a "covering" index, which adds another performance boost.  (If you go with `COUNT(*)`, tacking `code` on the end is harmless but not helpful.)

If you want to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

One more thing.  If you add my composite index, Drop the index for the first column (probably `DROP INDEX 'state'`).

The `LIMIT 1` is useless since `SELECT COUNT(..) FROM ..` will always give exactly 1 row.  (It is also harmless.)

**More**

`FULLTEXT` indexing is intended for lengthy text strings, not dates.

`DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` should be used for dates/times.  `VARCHAR` makes it difficult to compare dates.

11 "date" columns -- This seems strange.  Maybe "date" does not mean "date"?

Comment: thank you. your answer is below because too long as a comment:

Comment: @aynaz - I see nothing "below"; to what do you refer?

Comment: sorry, I have edited my question. please see again  that

Comment: Adding the composite index should help performance a lot.  If it does not, please provide a new `EXPLAIN` so we can check whether it is actually being used.  Meanwhile, I added a few tips on the schema.

Comment: added composite index and was very helpful. I hope it wasn't negative effect in other situations

Comment: my date is persian and stores with delimiter "/". for that use as varchar.

Comment: Changing the "Locale" might take care of the different syntax of dates.  In any case, it is almost always better to "fix" data as it is `INSERTed` instead of having to deal with it in `SELECT`.

Comment: See if this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570884/how-to-change-gregorian-date-to-persian-date-in-javascript/53894209  or  https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/24465147.html or https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_cal_jdtogregorian.asp or https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28380/Persian-Calendar-in-PHP